# Name the property $f(x) \ge x$

Tags: inequality, terminology, order-theory

It's a really one of the simplest properties you could imagine for a function. But I haven't been able to find a name for it. What do you call a function $f$ with the following property:

$$f(x) \ge x$$

Note, this is not monotonicity. Monotonicity is the following property:

$$x \ge y \implies f(x) \ge f(y)$$

Comment: It's called inflationary - although I've only ever seen this used in the context of Posets. If this is for a calculus question, I'd suggest just writing it out.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourbaki%E2%80%93Witt_theorem

Comment: I've seen it called an *expansion*.

Comment: If it's expansion as in the opposite of a contraction wouldn't it be $f(x) > x$?

Comment: I propose it be called "svenningson's property"

Comment: Thanks! Never heard the term inflationary in this context before but it makes sense.

Comment: The caveat is that inflationary specifically refers to this type of function in a particular kind of poset (chain-complete). I'm not sure it's applicable out of this context.

Comment: I've called it *enlarging*, but that's not a standard term to my knowledge.

Comment: @GitGud what would be the the converse of expansion? Contraction?

Comment: @svenningsson I don't know. The source where I saw *expansion* doesn't deal with the dual $f(x)\leq x$. Contraction might be ambiguous.

Comment: It seems strange to me that this question was closed. It seems succinct and well-posed, with a possible definitive answer being available. I'm not sure how much context could reasonably be given to such a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, this property is called *expansion*, as the element $x$ can be expanded, or stretched-out and thus contained in, the element $f(x)$.

However, this property is also termed *reflexivity*.

Why? Well, recall that a relation is reflexive if it relates identical elements.
More precicely,

$\;\;\; R \text{ reflexive}
\\\equiv \forall x:: \; x \, R \, x
\\\equiv \forall x,y:: \; x = y \implies x \, R \, y
\\\equiv \forall x,y:: \; x \, I \, y \implies x \, R \, y \text{, where $I$ is the identity relation: $I=\{(x,y)\,|\,x=y\}$}
\\\equiv I \subseteq R
$

Even more so, recall that an ordering $\leq$ on elements can be lifted to functions by $$f \overset{.}{\leq} g \,:\equiv\, (\forall x :: f \ x \leq g \ x)$$
With this, and letting $1$ be the identity function $x \mapsto x$, we have
$$f \text{ reflexive } \ \equiv \ 1 \overset{.}{\leq} f$$

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

<sup>The following is probably not what you're after, but perhaps it's mildly educational.</sup>

A somewhat convoluted way to describe your function would be to say:

> Every element is a post-fixed point.

An element $x$ is a fixed point of $f$ if $f(x)=x$. It is a pre-fixed point if $f(x)\leq x$, and it is a post-fixed point if $f(x)\geq x$.

Comment: It's an interesting suggestion since the question came up in the context of a program analysis which is indeed computed using fixed points. However, the $f$ in our case in not the transfer function we wish to compute the fix point of, but rather part of the property we wish to establish about the program. So using the post-fixed point term would most likely lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

inflationary or progressive. anyone can do . Both are one at the same thing

Answer (score -1):

I call it the opposite of a contraction; ie the concave variant; it would follow from star concavity at $x_0=0$ where $F(x_0=0)\geq 0$with
now as $$F(1)=1 \land \text{dom(F)}=[0,1]$$.

star concavity at 0 $$\forall (t\in [0,1]):\forall (x \in [0,1]):F((1-t)\times x_0+t\times y )\geq t\times F(y)+(1-t)\times F(x_0)$$.

ie
$$\to F(t\times y)=F( (1-t)\times 0+ t\times y)\geq (1-t)\times F(0)+t\times f(y)$$

As $(t,1-t)\in [0,1]\land F(x_0=0)\geq 0$

$$\to F(t\times y)\geq (1-t)\times F(0)+t\times f(y)\geq  t \times F(y)$$

star concavity  at $0$ with $F(0)\geq 0(B)$
$$\to (B)F(t\times y)\geq t\times F(y)$$

(2) now as $$F(1)=1 \land \text{dom(F)}=[0,1]$$.

$$t=x \to F(x)=F(t)$$
$$F(x)=F(t)= F(1 \times t)\to F(x)=F(1\times t)$$
concavity

$$\to F(x)=F(1\times t)\geq t\times F(1)$$

substitution of $F(1)=1$ 
$$\to F(x)\geq t\times F(1)=1\times t=t$$
$$\to F(x)\geq t $$=

where t=x so:
**$$\to F(x)\geq x$$**