# Terminology for functions such that $f(x)\ge x$ for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, terminology, dynamical-systems, order-theory

Is there a common terminology for a real function $f$ such that $$f(x)\ge x$$ for all $x$? same question for the conditions $\forall x,f(x)>x$; $\forall x,f(x)\le x$; $\forall x,f(x)<x$.

(I'm not specific about the domain of definition, I have in mind functions from $\mathbf{R}_+$ to itself but I don't expect this to be important, it could be from any interval to any other, or even from any totally ordered set to itself.)

If I had to coin a terminology I would say something like "dynamically non-decreasing" but it's a bit ugly.

Comment: A function with $f(x)<x$ is sometimes called regressive.

Comment: I am not aware of any terminology for exactly those functions, but you might want to look into [Landau Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) which can be used for expressing differend bounds of functions.

Comment: @flawr: I don't mean anything asymptotic. I really mean what I wrote and Landau notation is irrelevant

Comment: I don't think the downvote is fair. The condition ($\forall x,f(x)\ge x$) is very natural in dynamics, when we study how the sequence $(x,f(x),f(f(x)),\dots,f^{\circ n}(x),\dots)$ behaves (then it is an non-decreasing sequence).

Comment: These posts seem related (although they are not asking specifically about real functions): [Name the property $f(x) \ge x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/846074), [Terminology for properties of functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/91141).