# Name of property: $\phi (x)\geq x$

Tags: terminology, order-theory

Let $X$ be a preordered set and $\varphi : X\to X$ a function (can assume monotone if useful for the answer). Does the property of $\forall x\in X: \varphi (x) \geq x$ have a standard name?

Comment: In some contexts, this is called *extensive*. See [Closure operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator).

Comment: Is $\phi x=\phi(x)$ or another action of $\phi$ on $x$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde the former.

Comment: OK, I have edited it. The same question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240438/terminology-for-functions-such-that-fx-ge-x-for-all-x).

Comment: I like the term *increasing* even though it sometimes is used as synonym for monotone.